# undefined method `bytesize' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What mean this error ?

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `bytesize' for nil:NilClass):
```

And how i can resolve it? only i need breif example..

Note : I need information about this error in general, in my case or my code hard to resolve because of that i need only information.
Thanks you all

Comment: You most likely have a string that is nil.

Comment: It means you have `obj.bytesize` somewhere in your code with `obj` being `nil`. You resolve this error by ensuring that `obj` isn't `nil` in the first place. The full error message usually includes a file and line that should point you in the right direction.

Comment: I have seen this error with AWS S3 SDK. Uploaders sometimes break with a recent update of S3 SDK.

Comment: thank you all that it !

Comment: @Stefan please put your answer out of here to vote it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need information about this error in general [...]

[`NoMethodError`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/NoMethodError.html) is raised whenever you call a method that the receiver doesn't respond to.

The error message contains the method's name, the receiver and its class:

```
"foo".bar
# NoMethodError (undefined method `bar' for "foo":String)
#                                  ^^^      ^^^^^ ^^^^^^
#                                method   receiver class
```

> [...] in my case

Your method is `bytesize` and the receiver is `nil`. Somewhere in your codebase you have something like:

```
obj.bytesize
```

with `obj` being `nil`. Most likely, `obj` wasn't set properly.

I assume that `obj` is supposed to be a string because in the Ruby core and standard library only `String` implements [`bytesize`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/String.html#bytesize-method).

> And how i can resolve it?

The error message / backtrace usually contain file and line numbers that should point you in the right direction.

You resolve the error by ensuring that `obj` isn't `nil` in the first place.